# Searching for a german MIPS Processor Explaintation

Tags: assembly, mips

I'm currently searching for a german MIPS Manual, explaining how the processor works, it's operations and all that stuff like the MIPS IV-ISA PDF Document. The problem is: My english is really bad, I'm even doubting, that you can understand me. And reading stuff in english and translating it into my language is pretty hard for me. And because I don't want to misunderstand anything, I'm searching for a german MIPS Manual.

I'm currently working on an ASM Patching tool for a N64 Game, where I need to know how the processor actually works, what it does. Knowing the instructions of MIPS is not enough.

Mainly I'm searching for a german MIPS R4000/R4200 Manual.

Thank you in advance,
Cajetan.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

English first ...

Your English as far as phrasing this question is nowhere near as bad as you think - it's clearly understandable and complete. That said, this doesn't necessarily mean you'll get better answers here than what the omniscient garbage pile spits out when asked ... a few leads, not exhaustive, and not MIPS4000 specific ... so less useful to you than you ask for. What one finds are largely links to websites at German universities using MIPS / MIPS Simulators for teaching.

German ...

So schlecht wie du denkst ist dein Englisch gar nicht - die Frage ist klar verstaendlich formuliert, und vollstaendig. Allerdings bedeutet das nicht unbedingt, dass du hier bessere Antworten bekommst als per Frage an die [Allwissende Muellhalde](https://www.google.co.uk/search?q=%22MIPS%22%20%22Befehlssatz%22). Jene spuckt einige Antworten aus, allerdings nicht so umfassend wie du gerne haettest, und auch nicht MIPS4000-spezifisch. Das meiste was man findet sind Links zu Webseiten von Unis, die MIPS und/oder MIPS-Simulatoren zu Lehrzwecken verwenden:

- [MIPS (2000) Intro, TU Dresden](http://www.mr.inf.tu-dresden.de/studium/winter/infet1/docs/mips64/mips.html)
- [MIPS 2000 via SPIM Emulator, Karlsruhe Technische Informatik](http://ti.ira.uka.de/TI-2/Spim/Spim_Tutorial.pdf)
- [MIPS Assembler](http://www.uni-ulm.de/fileadmin/website_uni_ulm/iui.inst.050/vorlesungen/wise1112/ti2/TI2-falk-WS1112-5_MIPS_Assembler.pdf), Technische Informatik II
  (aus Vorlesung '[Grundlagen der Rechnerarchitektur](http://www.uni-ulm.de/in/es/lehre/archiv/winter-20112012/ti2.html)', fundamentals of computer architecture) - sehr ausfuehrliche Einfuehrung in den MIPS Befehlssatz
- [Vorlesung Rechnerarchitektur (Lecture 'computer architecture')](http://www.informatik.tu-cottbus.de/~fsi/alt/skripte/proz_WS99/proz-6.pdf)
  (BTU Chemnitz, relevant bzgl. Unterschiede MIPS3000 -> MIPS4000 sind Abschnitt 6.2 / 6.4)

Nach kurzem Durchblaettern muss ich allerdings sagen, dass der Befehlssatz und die Architektur-Besonderheiten (pipeline struktur, caches, ...) zwar gut abgedeckt sind, aber Verweise auf Kontroll-Register etc. fehlen; ob du vollkommen ohne die englischen Orginal-MIPS-Dokumente auskommst, ist daher schwer zu sagen.

waere ich du ... wuerde ich die obigen Dokumente zusammen mit dem [MIPS4000 User's Manual](http://techpubs.sgi.com/library/manuals/2000/007-2489-001/pdf/007-2489-001.pdf) benutzen um die Englisch-Luecken per "Kontext" zu fuellen ... das User's manual beschreibt den System Control Coprocessor - `CP0`, die FPU - `CP1` und die MMU recht ausfuehrlich.

Viel Glueck !

Comment: Ich danke dir vielmals. Naja, dann werde ich wohl eigene Lücken in meinem Englisch füllen müssen.